# Will a yeast that ferments at higher temps stop fusels?

Tags: yeast, fermentation-temperature

I have trouble with controlling temps and do not have much room for my growing collection of fermentation bins but I'm trying the swamp cooler for my 5L DemiJohn white wine kit. I'm gonna get some new ale/lagers on the go but I 'd like to know if the Mangrove Jack M10 Workhorse yeast which can ferment up to 32c would produce less fusels as it's able to hit higher temps?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't.  Yeast companies generally overestimate the high end temps.  They tell you where the yeast will work best, not necessarily the temps that make the best beers.  And no matter what the high end is, you'll always get better results by pitching at the low end (or below) of the stated temp range.  The first 72 hours are the most critical.  If you can keep the temps in the mid 60s for the first few days, after that it doesn't matter nearly as much.  Pitching at 32c almost guarantees fusels, no matter what strain of yeast you use.

Comment: Good advice thanks. Sadly even with a swamp cooler I'm hitting 24c

Comment: Drop some frozen water bottles into that swamp cooler too @jay

Comment: *sanitized* Frozen, water bottles. AKA, sanitize the water bottles before dropping them in. In this case boiling is not recommended :P

Comment: If they go in the swamp cooler, there is no need to sanitize them.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the fermentation temp, the greater your chances of fusels.

Comment: I've got a feeling it's going to be fusel city but with the ice I'm down to 22 not sure how much damage is done as I'm in to 72hrs